# Gimp arrow_brushes_BW colorize

Tags: gimp, brush

How to colorize GIMP arrow_brushes_BW http://www.gimphelp.org/arrow_brushes_BW_2.html ?
[image]

I mean when i try use some another brush on same RGB document with some arbitrary Foreground Color like red or green i received expected result. In same time when i switch brush to arrow character i receive only black color result without any gray-color variations.

[image]

Arrow brush **Tool Option**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These brushes (at least the one I tried) are RGB brushes. For Gimp there are two kind of brushes:

- **RGB**: these are colored shapes on transparent backgound, so they carry their own color
- **Grayscale**: these are black shapes on white background: they work like a "mask" where the white is the shape and the black is transparent (partial opacity can be achieved with gray). These brushes assume the foreground/background color.

So if you want these brushes to work as you wish you can to convert them to grayscale:

1. Open the brush in Gimp (`File>Open`)
2. Convert to grayscale (`Image>Mode>Grayscale`)
3. Re-export them (`File>Overwite`, Ctrl-Shift-S)

You will have to refresh your brushes (or restart Gimp) to make Gimp take the new format.

These brushes are from 2008, I suspect better options have been made available since.

Comment: How to detect in brushes palette which are Grayscale and which are RGB?

Comment: @Obelix The fact the brush isn't taking on the foreground colour is enough to demonstrate that it isn't in greyscale mode. In the brushes panel you can right click a brush and choose *Open Brush as Image*. Once open, you can check the image mode using *Image > Mode*

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using parts of both the answer and the comment.

The full workflow I followed was:

1. **Right click** on desired brush.
2. Click on '*Open Brush as Image*'.
3. **Image** > '*Mode*'.
4. As predicted, '*RGB*' was selected. Change this by clicking on the '*Grayscale*' radio button.
5. **File** > '*Export As...*'
6. Append '_grayscale' (or rename however you prefer) to the end of the file name keeping the *.**GBR** file extension & click '*Export*'.
7. In the '*Brushes*' dialog box, click the '*Refresh*' button (circular arrow).

This loaded the brush into GIMP without the need for restart and it immediately functioned as desired allowing for placement of red arrows since I already had red as the forecolor.